# Tableau Prep + Python: Unknown string format: 2018-09-12Z

Tags: python, tableau-api, string-formatting, facebook-prophet

I am trying to have a connection between Tableau Prep and Python to use the Prophet package to forecast the value of one column in my dataset. However I received the following error:

> *System error: Something went wrong when running the script. Verify that there are no errors in the script, then try again. ParserError :
> Unknown string format: 2018-09-12Z*

I checked the data and there is no errors within it, all of it has format 'DD/MM/YYYY'.

My input data has two columns:
|Date       |   Activated |
|-----------|-------------|
|09/12/2021 |     380     |
|...        | ...         |
|10/12/2018 |     240     |

My Python code looks like follows and it works correctly itself and gives the results:

````
import pandas as pd
from fbprophet import Prophet

def fbprophet_usage(df):

    df = df[["Date","Activated"]]  
    df.columns = ["ds", "y"]   
    df["ds"] = pd.to_datetime(df["ds"])
    model = Prophet()
    
    model.fit(df)
    print(model)
    
    future = model.make_future_dataframe(periods = 52, freq = 'W-MON')
    
    df = model.predict(future)
    df['ds']=df['ds'].dt.date
    return pd.DataFrame(df)


def get_output_schema():
    return pd.DataFrame({
            'ds' : prep_date(),
            'yhat': prep_int()
            })```



Did someone have the similar problem with Tableau Prep and Python connection?
````